# How to fetch attributes of any action class into another jsp page?

Tags: jsp, struts2

Can Someone Please tell me

"How to fetch attributes of any action class into another jsp page?"

i am having an actionclass "FindQuestion.java" which have an attribute "private int ra,ua;". I have made the getter and setter of both "ra" and "ua". Now i have another jsp page "home.jsp" which displays  few of the attributes of "FindQuestion.java" in `<s:property value=""/>` tag, which is loaded upon an action with reference to "FindQuestion.java". There is also a form with a "check" button which takes an integer from user with the `<s:select name ="ua" (list of integers) />` tag.

I need to fetch another attribute "ra" from "FindQuestion.java" which will be only used to compare its value with the value of "ua" (from select tag) upon the action of "check" button. If these are equal then shows message "Match Successfull" otherwise "Matching Failed". [ra is not to be displayed on jsp page].

Can someone suggest what java or any other coding is to be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use HttpSession to set the variable as session attribute. Later in your jsp page you can use `<s:test> <s:if> <s:else>` etc.

Comment: Can someone solve my aother problem..?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487435/how-to-setup-an-action-link-to-delete-the-row-from-the-table-loaded-from-the-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are doing the match in action class(not jsp):
Declare a hidden field in your **home.jsp** form

```
<s:hidden name="ra" value="%{ra}"/>
```

(`value` attribute in my knowledge is not required here because the variable name is the same).

In your action class where you are matching the variables declare this variable(with getter/setter). You can then compare the variables then.

Comment: Hi Anu, Can u solve this problem too.. ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Comment: Sorry dude, I have never worked with cookies. I can try something during weekends