# How to setup an action link to delete the row from the table loaded from the table when using struts2

Tags: struts2, action

I want to delete a row persistently from a table stored in the database which is being displayed on the jsp page. I have a link `Delete` (for each row) to delete the row on a single click.

My jsp code is :

```
    <s:iterator value="topperList" >
      <tr>
         <td><s:property value="uid"/></td>
         <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
         <td><s:property value="password"/></td>
         <td><s:property value="sex" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="city" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="abuse" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="lastlogin" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="points" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="joined" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="email" /></td>
         <s:url id="url" action="delete" >
           <s:param name="uid"><s:property value="uid" /></s:param>
         </s:url>
         <td><s:a href="%{url}">Delete</s:a></td>
      </tr> 
  </s:iterator>
```

My code in action class is :

```
private Integer uid;

public Integer getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(Integer uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
public String delete() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Users user = (Users) session.load(Users.class, this.getUid());
        if (null != user) {
            session.delete(user);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
           return SUCCESS;
    }
```

action code in struts.xml :

```
<action name="delete" class="com.rambo.action.FindToppers" method="delete" >
        <result name="success">buser.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

But i am getting the error :

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [beans.Users#0]
```

I have seen there is a proper row in table `USERS with uid=56`. But it shows No row with the identifier exists.
However i am not getting any server error logs.
Can some one point out what can be the problem.

Comment: Can you put the hibernate annotations (or XML file) from the `User` class?

Comment: Hi, if you wanna put more actions in the same class, you should return `string` instead `void`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 : then what string should i return from the delete() method and where to return..?

Comment: `SUCCESS`, your result is also `SUCCESS`, and you should not use `chain`

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I will just try it now. And i get back soon with the status of the problem.

Comment: @Pigueiras I have edited my question.. just see below the jsp code.. There is hibernate mapping for the "Users" class. Can you please post your answer as well..?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the `uid` value in your action class? In your exception `[beans.Users#0]` is mentioned i.e. 0 is set as the uid. Try to print(s.o.p) the value of `uid` before the query.

Answer (score 0):

private Integer cid;

This should be public and you might change it to be an int

Comment: @Spunog : I have getCid() method which is already public and i am fetching the only through this public getCid(). So i didn't get why i should do that. And further there is no problem with Integer which have no problem there.Can u suggest some other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. The problem is that the attribute `cid` in the action is `null` (you can do a `System.out.println(cid)`). If `null` is printed probably you will have to catch the url parameters with `ParameterAware`.

Comment: I made some changes in the code to correct it. Uid is being fetched properly with exact value. But it has new error as shown in the edited question "org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [beans.Users#0]". I have seen there is proper row in table USERS with uid=56. But it shows No row with the identifier exists. Can u now point out my problem..?

Comment: Look at this search results for help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objectnotfoundexception+hibernate. I can't help you with this error, sorry :(